# jQuery to run differently on even and odd number of click

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate

I have a button I wanna animate and reposition when it is clicked, but then when it is clicked a second time i want it to "fly" back to its original position. To that I thought I could make a function to run on even and odd clicks, but it dosent seem to work.. Anyone tried something similar, or can se a flaw in my code or logic??

```
$('#ure_knap').on('click', function() {
    var click = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (click % 2 == 1) {
        $('.ure_billeder').show();
    }else{
        $('.ure_billeder').hide();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code isn't incrementing clicks.

```
$('#ure_knap').on('click', function() {
    var click = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (click % 2 == 1) {
        $('.ure_billeder').show();
    }else{
        $('.ure_billeder').hide();
    };
    $(this).data('clicks',click+1);
});
```

but, on the other hand...why not just use `.toggle()`, which will do the same thing based on what I see.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're never setting the data attribute, so it never changes.

It seems easier to just use a boolean

```
$('#ure_knap').on('click', function() {
    var click = $(this).data('clicks');

    if (click) {
        $('.ure_billeder').show();
    }else{
        $('.ure_billeder').hide();
    };

    $(this).data('clicks', !click); // you have to set it

});
```

```js
$('#ure_knap').on('click', function() {
  var click = $(this).data('clicks');

  if (click) {
    $('.ure_billeder').show();
  } else {
    $('.ure_billeder').hide();
  };

  $(this).data('clicks', !click); // you have to set it

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ure_knap">click</div>
<br/>
<div class="ure_billeder">Tada</div>
```

but in this case you could also use `toggle`

```
$('#ure_knap').on('click', function() {
    $('.ure_billeder').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Yeah I know toggle would be much easier if I just wanted to hide/show, but i also want to reposition the button clicked, and if clicked again i want it back to the starting position, and i can't use toggle for that :)

Comment: I figured you were trying to do more, and a boolean flag is the way to go for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `data` attribute with the click count. However your construct is so simple you could reduce it to:

```
$('#ure_knap').on('click', function() {
    $('.ure_billeder').toggle();
});
```

But then again, you may just have simplified the code for the sake of asking the question:

```
$('#ure_knap').on('click', function() {
    var click = +$(this).data('clicks') || 0;
    if (click % 2 == 1) {
        $('.ure_billeder').show();
    }else{
        $('.ure_billeder').hide();
    };
    $(this).data('clicks',click+1);
});
```

```js
$('#ure_knap').on('click', function() {
    var click = +$(this).data('clicks') || 0;
    if (click % 2 == 1) {
        $('.ure_billeder').show();
    }else{
        $('.ure_billeder').hide();
    };
    $(this).data('clicks',click+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ure_knap">Click</button>
<div class="ure_billeder">Content</div>
```